# Visual Studio 2022 missing several project templates

Tags: visual-studio

For the past week I've been trying to install Visual Studio on my main computer to learn dotnet development, but I couldn't make it work.
I was expecting something like this to show up

[image]

But instead this is my actual workspace

[image]

I checked the option for ASP.Net development, so I didn't miss that part in case you're wondering.

[image]

Right now I managed to install Visual Studio on my laptop and I don't know why the same process isn't working here.

To be more clear I have multiple storage devices.

[image]

It might be the cause of this somehow, I don't really know.
I can't even use the newest framework for a simple console application:

[image]

I've tried to install the dotnet from the website too (I picked that version that was compatible "x64") and it didn't work either. It should've been something so simple I dont'k know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem!
At this point I've tried everything (I might have uninstalled/installed Visual Studio at least 10 times), but when I opened the installer window, there was a **repair** option. At first I didn't think it would work, but it actually solved my problem.

[image]

[image]